# Resolving EddyStone EID using Android Beacon Library

Tags: android, beacon, eddystone

I'm trying to resolve the EID of a (RadiusNetwork 4X) beacon that was registered with Google using the Android Beacon Library. I want to use the google API key, as opposed to o-auth to achieve that.

The documentation for the library advises to use this:

```
EidResolver resolver = getEidResolverForGoogleOAuthToken(googleOAuthToken);
String beaconName = resolver.resolve(ephemeralId);
```

I'm a bit at a loss. Where is this function located? It doesn't seem to be part of the Android Beacon Library. Neither does it seem to be part of the Google Proximity API - that's all web based as it looks? Is there any full example for this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EID resolver is a proposed addition to the Android Beacon Library that has not been merged into a formal release, which explains why you cannot find it.  The docs hint at this, but it is admittedly unclear.

In order to use the function, you must use a branch build of the library.  If you need help doing that, contact me through my profile link and I will assist.

You can see the pull request for this change on the library's GitHub repo here: https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/pull/364

The resolver is designed to support an API key using a separate constructor, but it has been so long since I tried it, I cannot remember if it was fully tested and working:

```
EidResolver getInstanceWithGoogleApiKey(String googleProximityBeaconApiKey, String resolutionAttachmentNamespacedType)
```

The only reason this has not been merged to a formal release is due to limited interest in helping test it. (You are the first one to ask about it in over a year!)

If you are up for a little back and forth getting it working for you, we can probably get this merged into a formal release at last.

Comment: So, I spent some time on this, and while it seemed that the o-auth solution worked, it didn't work with the API key. However, even interacting directly with the Google Proximity API I didn't manage to get it to work with the API key using the getforobserved function. It DID work for the simple UID EddyStone beacons though, it just didn't work for EID. So maybe this function has changed or I'm using it wrong. 

O-auth was good enough for me, but I actually ended up decrypting it myself on the server (the app sends the ephemeral id to the server), which is actually much more secure.

Comment: So unfortunately I wasn't able to test it properly with you, but maybe this helps nonetheless. So no need to push anything yet, as of now this is good enough for me. Thanks!